# React Native fetch promise .then() not executing immediately

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I'm using React Native to build an app for iOS and Android. In there, I'm simply calling fetch function from an external function once a button is tapped. The fetch function sends a POST request to a link and gets back a JSON response (JSON is correct, tested with Postman in various ways).

The issue is that the code after .then() is not executed immediately, but after I tap on the screen or go back using the navigation or perform some sort of minor actions. Here's the code that I used:

**CALLING CODE FROM FUNCTION**

```
verify() {
  this.setState({
    pressed: true
  });

  var self = this;
  var theURL = "<URL>"; //Removed for question

  fetch(theURL, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      uidOrEmail: this.state.email,
      code: this.state.value
    })
  })
.then(res => res.json())
.then(function(data) {
  console.log(data); //PROBLEM: This doesn't execute immediately
}
```

**BINDING**
I'm also binding this function in the constructor like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  console.log(this.props.navigation.state.params.email);

  this.state = {
    email: props.navigation.state.params.email,
    value: '',
    pressed: false
  };

  this.verify = this.verify.bind(this);
}
```

**INVOKING FUNCTION FROM UI**

```
<Button
  disabled={this.state.pressed}
  onPress={this.verify}
  >{!this.state.pressed ? 'Verify' : 'Verifying...'}</Button>
```

*To summarize:* Fetch function not resolving promise immediately.

**EDIT**

Some more information:

The fetch link is actually a Firebase function's link. How that function is returning:

```
response.status(200).send({status: 200, token: "ABC"});
```

Comment: That's because `fetch` makes an HTTP call that may take some time?

Comment: To build on that above comment, `fetch` is asynchronous. It's not supposed to execute immediately.

Comment: That's what the .then() function is for, isn't it? To wait till fetch returns something and then execute it?

Comment: "//PROBLEM: This doesn't execute immediately" <-- you mean immediately after the JSON parse, right?  I'm not sure how you know when that occurred.  In that last then, you'll want to setState with the button .pressed == false again anyway.   Please add that code there and report what you find.

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` will return a `Promise` object, the callbacks added by `then()` will be called after the promise is success. If the promise failed, the callback added by `catch()` will be called.

you can check `fetch` and `promise` document in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise.