# React Native fetch .then not executing code, depending on contents

Tags: react-native

Within a React native app, I have the following fetch call:

```
fetch("https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        console.log('HI THERE')
        //console.error(responseJson);
    });
```

Leaving it as is, when the fetch call is executed, the `.then` does not appear to execute ('HI THERE' does not get printed).  However, if I uncomment the line containing `console.error(responseJson);`, then the whole `.then` gets executed.

A similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45737535/react-native-fetch-promise-then-not-executing-immediately), but I'm not entirely sure if the problem occuring there is exactly what I'm experiencing.  Also, the answer has to do with the fact that fetch calls are asynchronous and we cannot expect them to execute immediately; the problem I am experiencing is that the fetch call does not execute the `.then` at all (I have waited several minutes several times) until that one line is uncommented AND the app is reloaded AND the fetch call is re-executed.

Why does this happen - and how can I fix it so it executes as expected? Is it a React Native bug - possibly related to [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6679) one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the issue was the method I used to run the app session.  I was using `sudo npm start`, but I fixed it by using `sudo exp start` instead.  I'm not entirely sure what the exact issue was (but my best guess is that something in `npm start` causes console logs to remain hidden in a buffer until an error is logged).

Comment: This link may also be relevant for some people with similar problems, though I have not tried it myself yet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40030709/react-native-cant-see-console-logs-when-i-run-application-from-xcode

Answer (score 1):

I've tried it with the snack and it works just fine for me
https://snack.expo.io/@troublediehard/fetch-test-app

But anyway if something does not appear in `then` probably it fails and you can find details in `catch`. Try to check it like this

```
fetch("https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json")
.then(response => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
    console.log('HI THERE')
    // console.error(responseJson);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```